# How to write TypeScript meaningful Interface properties name and not pay on JS file size

Tags: typescript, minify, naming

In the last month, I am building in TypeScript a communication layer for a product and I notice I have lots of properties in the interfaces which I will use in my code. The names of the properties can be 2-4 words long, and sometimes even 5-6 words for simple explanations, unfortunately, when I transpile and minified to final JS I notice the minifier, uglyfier, is not able to shrink the size of those properties because they are Object Level properties and not a function level variables.

Technically I want those points:

1. I don't want to write short names because of the sizing issue which will bytes-explode the JS file size.
2. I want other developers to **not** limited call properties names with specific length names.
3. Make the final names something like `a1` or `b1` in the final JS but the developers will see `NextRecommendationsBatch`.
4. It will be super simple to know where this param is in usage.
5. It will keep it strong type checking for all levels and auto-completion.
6. Want **all** long names will be gone in compile, transpile, time.

I know those are lots to ask, but today we need smaller JS files. I will be happy for suggestions.

Code Example, link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAyhMBGZAbwFgAoZC5EAVwFsAjaAeRgElJaBnALhoegDcZSsgTUoUCOABCGBAAtWIACYQAHgDFcC0AHNedRlCHlKIdWFlgFS1Zu3y9B-sbIBfMmQQB7EJzDIAPrKGHDc6Jg4%20MgAvETClGISUpZyiirqWtaOIPrIeAA0CRTmaqnZtpkOTsgATEWmJYbMbBw8%20QAMDW4CQA):

```js
interface DataSet1 {
    numberOfItems:number;
    currentBatchIndexFetching:number;
    nextBatchIndexFetching:number;
}

const _data:DataSet1 = {
    currentBatchIndexFetching: 1,
    nextBatchIndexFetching: 2,
    numberOfItems: 10,
};
```

You can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAyhMBGZAbwFgAoZC5EAVwFsAjaAeRgElJaBnALhoegDcZSsgTUoUCOABCGBAAtWIACYQAHgDFcC0AHNedRlCHlKIdWFlgFS1Zu3y9B-sbIBfMmQQB7EJzDIAPrKGHDc6Jg4%20MgAvETClGISUpZyiirqWtaOIPrIeAA0CRTmaqnZtpkOTsgATEWmJYbMbBw8%20QAMDW4CQA) on the editor right panel the final code, you will see it an issue with properties name.

```js
const _data = {
    currentBatchIndexFetching: 1,
    nextBatchIndexFetching: 2,
    numberOfItems: 10,
};
```

I found one I wants to share in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way that increases the code size and gives all the points I wrote above. I know it looks much a little intimidating, but it can reduce your code size tremendously.

Code can be seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgEQIZQwZTlARgDEBLOAGwBMYBvAWACgZmYA5FAIzgCcB5AMwCSUOMggwAvDABEYEtIA0jFjADCibtwRQAQlmAALQWEpwAHkXyGSYAOaSZwDvKVMWrc7v1GT5y1Gs7B1lnRUYAX0ZGGxFufgxgOHQsXHwCWmUWAG1MbDxCUgpKADp2ZC4%20IRExAF0ALiRyngBuTOYclPziMipi9U1tPQCfUwsrAxtbesaK1rd23NSCnpKPMy9h41H-QKmGzhaIqIZQSFgAfUoUusWuh3p5mA68tMLe-q0wDcMtv3HJ%20owAiuFTPJbdIqlTxDH6%20MbDAF1GAAJhB2VurxWpQOlWEogggIIAAZXOE5kA):

```js
const enum DataSet1Field {
    NumberOfItems = "ni",
    CurrentBatchIndexFetching = "cbi",
    NextBatchIndexFetching = "nbi",
}

interface DataSet1 {
    [DataSet1Field.NumberOfItems]:number;
    [DataSet1Field.CurrentBatchIndexFetching]:number;
    [DataSet1Field.NextBatchIndexFetching]:number;
}

const _data:DataSet1 = {
    [DataSet1Field.CurrentBatchIndexFetching]: 1,
    [DataSet1Field.NextBatchIndexFetching]: 2,
    [DataSet1Field.NumberOfItems]: 10,
};
```

As we can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgEQIZQwZTlARgDEBLOAGwBMYBvAWACgZmYA5FAIzgCcB5AMwCSUOMggwAvDABEYEtIA0jFjADCibtwRQAQlmAALQWEpwAHkXyGSYAOaSZwDvKVMWrc7v1GT5y1Gs7B1lnRUYAX0ZGGxFufgxgOHQsXHwCWmUWAG1MbDxCUgpKADp2ZC4%20IRExAF0ALiRyngBuTOYclPziMipi9U1tPQCfUwsrAxtbesaK1rd23NSCnpKPMy9h41H-QKmGzhaIqIZQSFgAfUoUusWuh3p5mA68tMLe-q0wDcMtv3HJ%20owAiuFTPJbdIqlTxDH6%20MbDAF1GAAJhB2VurxWpQOlWEogggIIAAZXOE5kA) the solution will give you much smaller compiled code (after removing the code comments).

```js
const _data = {
    ["cbi"]: 1,
    ["nbi"]: 2,
    ["ni"]: 10,
};
```

So, you have more code in TypeScript, but the final code is smaller and by Show Usage per Enum Item for `DataSet1Field` I will see all the places it used in the code.

A note about IDEs, Intellij-IDEA is better by understanding more complex TypeScript code and will auto-complete better.

I hope it helps.

Comment: You're doing minifier job manually.. Which minifier do you use? Look at its docs, probably you'll find better solution

Comment: @AlekseyL. The minifiers can't minify properties of an Object, they keep it as is. I know it look like doing the Uglyfier/Minifier work but it will save you lots of bytes over the network and for large scale Apps it important.

Comment: They actually do if you tell them, check the docs  That's why I've asked which one do you use..

Comment: @AlekseyL. please send a link for the one you know doing it.

Comment: Here's webpack's default one. https://github.com/terser/terser#cli-mangling-property-names---mangle-props Of course you should be super careful when playing with it

Comment: Interesting tool, didn't know it. By the docs it unsafe to use the `--mangle-props` feature and I don't know how it will work with multiple files and when using the interface in lots of places. can it keep track?

Comment: Try it (probably regex option). Honestly I wouldn't go this path (both your solution and props mangling) before doing proper measurements and verifying that bundle size is really reduced (after applying gzip compression)

Comment: I am doing this in current project, reducing it by 3-4k only on the basic module. it another solution for TS, not the only one. I wanted to give this option for developer who seeking another way.